# Does xslt be used to add space after lowercase followed by Uppercase letter

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have some simple strings:

Ex:

> DeFacto, RightOfWay, HalfYearly etc

How can i insert a space between the lowercase and the uppercase using a function in xslt 2.0 or xslt 3.0.

Desire output:

> De Facto, Right Of Way, Half Yearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function: `replace('DeFacto, RightOfWay, HalfYearly', '(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})', '$1 $2')` gives `De Facto, Right Of Way, Half Yearly`.

Comment: Thank you @Marin Honnen. That was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code provided i've made a function for the replacement.

```
<xsl:function name="fn:InsertSpace">
    <xsl:param name="Text" />
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($Text, '(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})', '$1 $2')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Note that to return a string value from your function you should use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of` as the latter returns a text node.

Comment: ok, i've change the code using the xsl:sequnce instead of the xsl:value-of.